# How to limit border thickness to no more than 1 pixel in a fragment shader?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to setup a toon shader, but regardless of what I do, my border always ends up thicker than 1px in certain points:

[bad http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/wg.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/wg.png)

This is really bad. I'm using the following fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
    varying vec4 pos_var;
    uniform sampler2D rgb;
    uniform sampler2D depth;
    float dep(vec2 pos){
        return texture2D(depth,vec2(float(pos.x)/512.0,float(pos.y)/512.0)).x;
    }
    void main(void) {
        vec4 rgb = texture2D(rgb,vec2((pos_var.x+1.0)*0.5,(pos_var.y+1.0)*0.5));
        vec2 p = vec2(int(floor((pos_var.x+1.0)*0.5*512.0)), int(floor((pos_var.y+1.0)*0.5*512.0)));

        float d = dep(p);
        float dx = dep(vec2(p.x-1.0,p.y));
        float dX = dep(vec2(p.x+1.0,p.y));
        float dy = dep(vec2(p.x,p.y-1.0));
        float dY = dep(vec2(p.x,p.y+1.0));
        float t = 0.0002;
        gl_FragColor = (
            (dx>d+t) || 
            (dX>d+t) || 
            (dy>d+t) || 
            (dY>d+t)) 
            ? vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) 
            : rgb;
    }
```

This is determining whether a pixel is a border by comparing its depth to its neighbor's. Here, `depth` is a texture with the depth value of each pixel rendered on the first pass, and `rgb` is a texture with the colors. `dep` is a helper function to get the depth of a pixel, and `t` is an arbitrary tolerance. Does anyone have an idea on how I can limit the thickness of the borders to 1?

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Comment: @genpfault my bad, it is actually WebGL. So, I guess, 100?